# Getting undefined symbol error while dynamic loading of shared library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading

I am getting `undefined symbol` error while loading library dynamically.
Here is my code snippet that generates this error :

```
int main ()
{

    void *lib_handle = NULL;

    MyClass* (*create)();
    void (*destroy)(MyClass*);
    char *error;


    lib_handle = dlopen ("./libshared.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (lib_handle == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);

    } 

    create = (MyClass* (*)()) dlsym(lib_handle, "create_object");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
      exit(1);
   }

    destroy = (void (*)(MyClass*)) dlsym(lib_handle, "destroy_object");

    MyClass *myClass = (MyClass*) create;
    destroy(myClass);   

    dlclose(lib_handle);
}
```

But when I load library simply by commenting above code and exporting library path everything works like charm.

For dynamic linking I am using the following command on command prompt.

`g++ -Wl,--export-dynamic shared_user.cpp -ldl`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard the term "_name mangling_" ? That's what's probably happening here, you've got C++ code but are looking for an unmangled name. If you want this to work, declare the factory function as `extern "C" { create_object(...) ... }` in your code. Beyond that, you need to invoke it as `create()` because you're not performing a function call otherwise.

Comment: And so tag this as C++ and not C

Comment: To clarify: You need the `extern "C" { ... }` bit in the sourcecode for `libshared.so` to get the symbol names right. Also, if you want to test whether my hypothesis is correct, simply run "nm libshared.so" and see what the _actual_ names are.

Answer (score 14):

You're very likely seeing *Name Mangling* in action here.

If you want to use `dlopen()` / `dlsym()` with C++ shared libraries, you either need to:

1. declare the functions you want to lookup through `dlsym()` as `extern "C" { ... }` so that the C++ compiler creates *unmangled* names for them.
   This is only possible if the function you try to access is a non-member or static member function, and not overloaded (only a single signature); C++ can't create unmangled names in other situations.
   If one requested the compiler to do so via `extern "C" { ... }` and it's possible to create an unmangled name, it ends up verbatim in the ELF symbol table. You can then look it up using `dlsym()` exactly like you would for any C function.
2. Find out what the *mangled* name of the function is, and use that in your `dlsym()` call.

The latter you can do via the `nm` utility. For example:

```
$ nm libstdc++.a | grep -v '^ ' | grep unexpected
0000000000000000 T __cxa_call_unexpected
0000000000000000 T _ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE
0000000000000000 T _ZSt10unexpectedv
0000000000000000 T _ZSt14set_unexpectedPFvvE
0000000000000000 D _ZN10__cxxabiv120__unexpected_handlerE
```

These are the *mangled* names, what the C++ compiler has actually put into the ELF object. If you use the `-C` option to request `nm` to *demangle* the names for you, you get:

```
$ nm -C libstdc++.a | grep -v '^ ' | grep unexpected
0000000000000000 T __cxa_call_unexpected
0000000000000000 T __cxxabiv1::__unexpected(void (*)())
0000000000000000 T std::unexpected()
0000000000000000 T std::set_unexpected(void (*)())
0000000000000000 D __cxxabiv1::__unexpected_handler
```

That means for this lib, if you'd want to get the function pointer to `std::unexpected()` from it, you'd have to request `dlsym(hdl, "_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE");` to make the lookup succeed.

Comment: the explanation is correct in principle, but the example is slightly off: `std::unexpected()` is synonymous to `_ZSt10unexpectedv`, but `_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE` corresponds to `__cxxabiv1::__unexpected(void (*)())`.